# Create a Directory in AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using the boto3 library to create a S3 folder using python.(Want to create a directory 'c' in already existing directory structure like '/a/b'

```
s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
s3_client =put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='a/b/c/')
```

I am not getting any error but the directory is also not getting created. I cant really figure out the reason, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a typo in the code you show but it should give you an error. I think what you are trying to do is:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='a/b/c/')
print("Response: {}".format(response)) # See result of request.
```

Comment: If you follow up with:

response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='a/b/c/') 

Do you get a NoSuchKey error?

Comment: If so, you should have created the specified key '/a/b/c' under your defined bucket name. Make sure to refresh your S3 browser or your page in AWS console after running the pu_object command. If you still can't find it and are using AWS console to look for the created object, assure that you're console is set to match the region (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) in which the S3 object was created. You can check this in the top right corner of the browser next to your account name.

Comment: Additional note: I believe boto3 defaults to 'us-east-1'

Answer (score 0):

there are no such things as folders or directory in S3

to upload a file to your bucket you could use:

```
s3_client=boto3.client('s3')
# you have to provide my_binary_data
response = s3_client.put_object(Body=my_binary_data, Bucket=bucket_name, Key='a/b/c/')
```

where `Key` represents the name or your file

you can read more aboout `Client.put_object` [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=put_object#S3.Client.put_object)

Comment: I agree that S3 doesnt have any directory structure. I dont want to put any files, just create a blank directory.

Comment: do you want to create new bucket maybe ?

Comment: no, just want to create the directory, would place the files later.

Comment: @user2828360 That's not how S3 works. There is no such thing as an empty directory in S3